# how to print prime numbers using for loop in shell script

Tags: shell, for-loop

I want to print prime numbers using for loop in shell script. Please provide some suggestions.

actually I could able to print odd numbers from range of 1 to 100, but now I am unable to print prime numbers. Provide some script to print prime numbers

```
# cat prime.sh
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=1; i<=100; i++))

do

      output=$(( $i % 2))

      if [ $output -ne 0 ]

      then
      echo "We got odd numbers: $i"
      fi
done
```

Comment: You'll need to do some research about finding an algorithm to generate prime numbers (for example, Sieve of Eratosthenes), then try implementing it in the shell.

Comment: What is that you have tried till now for the prime numbers? It’ll be easier for the community if could provide the code snippet. 

Also, the way you are using the condition of %2 to check for odd numbers , just replace it with the condition for prime numbers

Comment: @glenn jackman: I am new to shell so asking someone to help, otherwise i would have researched. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: See https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#UNIX_Shell

Comment: Just print them `echo 1 3 5 7 11 13 17` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk: Good answer

Answer (score 0):

The below code returns the list of prime numbers within a specified range.

the below command returns the prime numbers between 10 to 30

`./filename.sh 10 30`

```
#!/bin/bash
# Check if a number is prime

# function to return whether prime or not
check_prime() {
    current_number=$1
    flag=0
    i=2

    while test $i -le `expr $current_number / 2`
    do
        if test `expr $current_number % $i` -eq 0
        then
            flag=1
        fi
        i=`expr $i + 1`
    done

    if test $flag -eq 0
        then echo $current_number
    fi
}

# Assign From and to number
from_number=$1
to_number=$2

for (( number=$from_number; number<=$to_number; number++ ))
do
    check_prime $number
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will Print all prime numbers upto given number & also print count of it
hope it helps !!

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "enter a number upto which you want the prime numbers"
read num
count=0
for (( n=2; n<=$num; n++ ))
do

t=1

if [ $n -lt 2 ]
then echo "Please give other  numbers than 0 and 1"
else
#echo $n
for (( i=2; i<$n; i++ ))
do
        #echo $n
        if (($n%i==0))
        then
        #echo "$n is not prime number"
        t=0
        break;
        fi
done
#echo $t
        if [ $t == 1 ]
        then
        echo "$n is a prime number"
        count=`expr $count + 1`
        fi
fi
done
echo "Total prime numbers upto $num are $count "
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash *(code tested using GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1))-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu))* comes with the powerful mechanism of **brace expansion** *{START..STOP..STEP}* which runs loops in order to obtain the result without explicit usage of `for`, `do` and `done`. This mechanism applied to the task of echoing of all odd numbers up to 100 cuts the necessary bash code for running an appropriate loop to:

```
echo {1..100..2} # prints all odd numbers up to 100
```

The above know-how, combined with the ability of Bash to perform arithmetic calculations including modulo division using the *$((ARITHMETIC_EXPRESSION))* syntax, can then be used to reduce the number of iterations in a loop echoing prime numbers up to 100:

```
printf "2 3 5 7 "
for p in {11..100..2}; do 
  if [ $(($p%3*$p%5*$p%7)) -ne 0 ]; then
    printf "$p "; # prints all primes in range from 11 to 100
  fi
done
```

Please *NOTICE* that in case of the range up to 100 the most straightforward and practical way of printing all of the primes using a bash script will be anyway:

```
echo "2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97"
```

Modification of the provided code to cover additionally the range of primes from 100 up to 1000 will need only some tiny adjustments like extending the range of the multiplications to all primes up to 31:

```
for p in {101..1000..2}; do 
# iterates over: 101 103 ... ... ... 995 997 999
  if [ $(($p%3*$p%5*$p%7*$p%11*$p%13*$p%17*$p%19*$p%23*$p%29*$p%31)) -ne 0 ]; then 
    # $p is not divisible by any prime in range up to 31, so
    # it must be a prime itself: 
    printf "$p "
 fi
done
```

Anyway, also in this case, the most straightforward way to get all these primes to *stdout* using a bash script would be:

```
echo "101 103 107 109 113 127 131 137 139 149 151 157 163 167 173 179 181 191 193 197 199 211 223 227 229 233 239 241 251 257 263 269 271 277 281 283 293 307 311 313 317 331 337 347 349 353 359 367 373 379 383 389 397 401 409 419 421 431 433 439 443 449 457 461 463 467 479 487 491 499 503 509 521 523 541 547 557 563 569 571 577 587 593 599 601 607 613 617 619 631 641 643 647 653 659 661 673 677 683 691 701 709 719 727 733 739 743 751 757 761 769 773 787 797 809 811 821 823 827 829 839 853 857 859 863 877 881 883 887 907 911 919 929 937 941 947 953 967 971 977 983 991 997"
```

For the sake of completeness below the shell script code using the *Sieve of Eratosthenes* approach making use of array variables supported by Bash *(copy/pasted here from [rosettacode.org](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#UNIX_Shell))*:

```
function primes {
  typeset -a a
  typeset i j
  a[1]=""
  for (( i = 2; i <= $1; i++ )); do
    a[$i]=$i
  done
  for (( i = 2; i * i <= $1; i++ )); do
    if [[ ! -z ${a[$i]} ]]; then
      for (( j = i * i; j <= $1; j += i )); do
        a[$j]=""
      done
    fi
  done
  printf '%s' "${a[2]}"
  printf ' %s' ${a[*]:3}
  printf '\n'
}
primes 1000
```